# What are the downsides of websockets in mobile applications?

Tags: mobile, websocket

I have a mobile application that needs to get updates from the server over a long period of time. And the user is moving a lot during that time (cell tower changes, bad reception, loss of connectivity, ...)

I now need to decide if I use frequent short calls to the server (I was thinking about everything 2 seconds) or use websockets.

My questions:

- What is more battery intensive, polling every two seconds or using websockets (and possibly checking connection status, handling reconnecting, ...)?
- Can the phone put the network stack in power save mode while there is an active websocket connection?